# ddrescue encounters read errors only, no good reads at all

Tags: linux, hard-drive, ddrescue, hfs+

I tried to rescue a disk connected via USB to a Linux box using [GNU ddrescue](http://www.gnu.org/software/ddrescue/ddrescue.html), but after running over the first 2 GB it couldn't rescue anything but instead reported only read errors. To avoid further disk damage I interrupted the process:

```
$ sudo ddrescue /dev/sdb hdimage mapfile
GNU ddrescue 1.25
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
     ipos:    2028 MB, non-trimmed:    2035 MB,  current rate:       0 B/s
     opos:    2028 MB, non-scraped:        0 B,  average rate:       0 B/s
non-tried:  998169 MB,  bad-sector:        0 B,    error rate:    262 kB/s
  rescued:        0 B,   bad areas:        0,        run time:      4m 24s
pct rescued:    0.00%, read errors:    31158,  remaining time:         n/a
                              time since last successful read:         n/a
Copying non-tried blocks... Pass 5 (forwards)^C
  Interrupted by user
```

The disk contains three partitions, with the second one being a HFS+ partition that can still be mounted, however accessing it results in I/O errors:

```
sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Sense Key : Medium Error [current] 
sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error
sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 1c f1 78 00 00 08 00
print_req_error: critical medium error, dev sdb, sector 1896824
Buffer I/O error on dev sdb2, logical block 185898, async page read
```

Before operating on the damaged disk I tested my setup with a healthy disk and I could rescue all the 80 GB of an `ext4` partition using the same command on the same machine and the same USB port.

Does it suggest that the disk is already dead, or am I doing something wrong? Maybe I should let `ddrescue` run further to see if it improves in later phases? What else could I try without risking further data loss?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this (particularly the log errors) suggest the disk is dead.  You have not done anything wrong, and this is not a ddrescue fault.

The next thing I might try would be to reinsert the disk (make sure you identify the new sdX number as these can change), and try running ddrescue in reverse with the following syntax:

```
 sudo ddrescue -R /dev/sdX hdimage mapfile
```

You can attempt this operation (in both forward and reverse directions) for as long as you have time - ddrescue will do its best.

Comment: You probably mean the `-R / --reverse` not the `-r n / --retry-passes=n` option?

Comment: The partition had several hundreds GB free, would it be reasonable to use `-S / --sparse` option to save space on output?

Comment: My biggest worry is, however, that each read attempt may cause new damage. Is it really so? Maybe handing the disk over to a company that does data recovery would be a safer option? Could they do better than the valued `ddrescue`?

Comment: You are right to be concerned. Although I confess I don't know how relevant this concern is for flash memory (its significant for HDD). If this data is that important, take it to a recovery firm, but make sure they have the ability to desolder the chips and read raw data.

Comment: I am not sure why are you mentioning flash memory here? In case I didn't make myself clear about what kind of disk it is: it's a 1 TB SATA HDD taken out of a late 2009 iMac, the label reads: "Seagate Barracuda 7200.12". It definitely has rotating disks in it.

Answer (score -1):

> My biggest worry is, however, that each read attempt may cause new damage. Is it really so?

Yes.

> Maybe handing the disk over to a company that does data recovery would be a safer option? Could they do better than the valued ddrescue?

Yes, because they can check the condition of the hardware instead of just trying to read sectors.